# Rudin: Real & Complex Analysis Thm 1.10

Tags: real-analysis

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ If $\mathcal{F}$ is any collection of subsets of $X$, there exists a smallest $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}^{*}$ in $X$ such that $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{M}^{*}$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $\Omega$ be the family of all $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{M}$ in $X$ which contain $\mathcal{F}$. Since the collection of all subsets of $X$ is such a $\sigma$-algebra, $\Omega$ is not empty. Let $\mathcal{M}^{*}$
be the intersection of all $\mathcal{M} \in \Omega$. It is clear that $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{M}^{*}$ and that $\mathcal{M}^{*}$ lies in
every a-algebra in X which contains $\mathcal{F}$.

To complete the proof, we have to
show that $\mathcal{M}^{*}$ is itself a a-algebra.
If $A_n \in \mathcal{M}^{*}$ for $n = 1,2,3, \dots $ and if $\mathcal{M} \in \Omega$, then $A_n \in \mathcal{M}$, so $ \cup A_n \in \mathcal{M}$,
since $\mathcal{M}$ is a a-algebra. Since $\cup A_n \in \mathcal{M}$ for every $\mathcal{M} \in \Omega$, we conclude that
$\cup A_n \in \mathcal{M}^{*}$. The other two defining properties of a a-algebra are verified in the same manner. $\square$

I understand $\mathcal{M}^{*}$ being an intersection of all the $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{M}$ on $X$, that contain $\mathcal{F}$. Follows the proof of $\mathcal{M}^{*}$ being a $\sigma$-algebra - since it's intersection of all $\mathcal{M} \in \Omega$, then if the $A_n$ sets are in $\mathcal{M}^{*}$, they must also be in all of the $\mathcal{M}$'s, so the countable union is there as well (the same applies for the complements, $\varnothing$ and the whole space).

Can we therefore generalize, that any intersection of $\sigma$-algebras must also be a $\sigma$-algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't generalize, that's precisely what they do! (i.e. showing that any intersection of $\sigma$-algebras is also a $\sigma$-algebra). To see this, just take $\mathcal F = \bigcap_{\mathcal M \in \Omega} \mathcal M$. The meaning of "smallest" is in the sense of inclusion, i.e. every other smaller $\sigma$-algebra is included in that minimal $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Right. Is there also a connection to the rationale behing the Tower property? (ie: for $s<t$ and $X_t$ a stochastic process: $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_t | \mathcal{F}_t]|\mathcal{F}_s] = \mathbb{E}[X_t |\mathcal{F}_s] $ where $\mathcal{F}_s $ is a filtration. ...maybe we don't even need to bother verifying that the smaller filtration is a $\sigma$-algebra, since we've got that from definition?

Comment: This identity is a bit different but the flavor is similar : if you think about $L^2(X, \mathcal F_0)$ as an Hilbert space (let's forget $L^1$ for a second... $\mathcal F_0$ denotes the initial $\sigma$-algebra in a filtration), then the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[X_t | \mathcal F_s]$ is a projection onto the subspace of $L^2(X, \mathcal F_s) \subseteq L^2(X, \mathcal F_t)$. The identity you just mentioned just saying that projecting onto some subspace and then projecting into a smaller subspace is just equivalent to projecting in the smaller subspace in one step.

Comment: I must admit I don't know what the "rationale behind the Tower property" stands for ; I've learned my stochastic calculus in French so maybe I'm aware of it, but that name doesn't ring a bell.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - for any collection of $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{M}$, just go through the steps of the proof for  the set $\mathcal{F}=\bigcap_{\mathcal{M}\in\Omega}\mathcal{M}$.

It is usually the case that the intersection of a set of sub<blah>s is a sub<blah>, and that the intersection of all the sub<blahs> containing <foo> is the smallest sub<blah> containing <foo>. This is certainly true for <blah>  = set, group, ring, field, for instance. It is also true for things like topologies, $\sigma$-algebras, and other mathematical structures consisting of nice collections of subsets of a set.